# pnp4nagios perfrormance report-regular expression pattern/filter

Tags: regex, linux, nagios, check-mk

I edited the cfg file "/opt/omd/sites/sitename/etc/pnp4nagios/pages" to include CPU, filesystem and memory.

Is it possible to report only for root volume (Filesystem / ) and not for
Filesystem /var, Filesystem /opt/omd etc.?

I've tried with regular expressions:

`^Filesystem[ ]\/
^Filesystem[]\/$
[Filesystem \/]`

But they all fail.

```
define  page  {
        use_regex 1
        page_name My Performance Report
}


define graph {
        host_name       host1 | host2 |
        service_desc    CPU|Memory|Filesystem     
        source        1                       
}
```

Comment: Most probably you do not need to escape `/` in `Filesystem\s/`. It matches a word `Filesystem` followed with any whitespace and then `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, maybe found solution: used this regex generator https://regex101.com
and got this: `Filesystem\s\/` which gives me what i want: Filesystem /

i really do hope it will work with pnp4nagios for check_mk

will know next week

Comment: Wiktor, when trying your solution,get error, mine doesn't throw an error but also doesn't work,it doesn't show any Filesystem